# Textures breaking in windows

Tags: rendering, texturing, blend4web

The problem is that the scene renders perfectly on all of my Linux and windows machines, but the textures get messed up on friend's windows machines.[image]

Comment: What is your friend using to render the files? It doen't look like he's using Blender. I suspect if you save the renders to an image file, and give the image file to your friend, the files will display as you expect. Welcome to BSE.

Comment: That looks like a normals issue maybe combined with a transparency problem. This sounds like a question for https://www.blend4web.com, unless @Blend4Web wants to take this one.

Comment: He is opening it in Chrome from .html file. This is an object in b4w .html. A csimple setup, just an object in an empty field. In Firefox, on the same system, it works like a charm.

Comment: Well this is an issue with either Blend4Web or one of the browsers, not Blender itself, so you should report this to the addon authors, at the link provided in my previous comment. I'm voting to close this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is either about Blend4Web or an issue cause by one of the Browsers and should probably be [reported to the addon authors](https://www.blend4web.com)